# Laravel Seeder on Server

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I just run seeder on my server using SSH but my connection is lost during progress, so I need to re-login the SSH.
my question is.
is the seeder still running?

Thank you.

Comment: Relevant - https://serverfault.com/questions/115968/ssh-session-drops-does-the-command-continue-executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on a [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/115968/ssh-session-drops-does-the-command-continue-executing) post.

> In most cases, no. Processes will be sent a SIGHUP on loss of terminal. You can prefix a command with 'nohup' to ignore the signal. See:
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: thank you, I just run seeder for crawling large data case.

Comment: If you run any long process tasks look at running it in `screen` so you can restore the process.